# Django rest: You do not have permission to perform this action during creation api schema

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to add some schema views to my django project (i used [this](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/schemas/) example)

My code:

```
def get_auth():
    auth = [
        path('', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
        path('register', RegisterApiView),
        path('token/obtain/', TokenObtainPairView),
        path('token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView),
    ]
    return auth 

def get_schema():
    schema_url_patterns = [
        path('api/auth', include(get_auth())),
    ]

    schema_view = get_schema_view(
        title='Auth Schema',
        url='/api/auth/',
        patterns=schema_url_patterns,
    )
    return schema_view


urlpatterns = [
  path('api/auth/', get_schema()),
]
```

And when I try to connect to /api/auth/ I encounter an error:

```
HTTP 403 Forbidden
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/coreapi+json
Vary: Accept

{
    "detail": "You do not have permission to perform this action."
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed that myself, error was in `get_auth()` method, I didn't add `as_view()` to `view` classes:

```
def get_auth():
    auth = [
        path('', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
        path('register', RegisterApiView.as_view({'post': 'create'})),
        path('token/obtain/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view()),
        path('token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view()),
        ]
    return auth
```